# Is there a way to add a script that runs before any elements are added to the DOM but that relies on the body element?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am attempting to check every mutation on a page using `MutationObserver`.

Is there a simple way to fix the following so I don't have to include it in the body (i.e. include it in the `<head>`) as an inline script?

The issue comes with the fact that I need the `bodyList` variable to be able to start monitoring items added to the page.

Obviously I can't use the onLoad event or anything as by then the mutations have all occurred (unless there is a way of accessing them after the fact I am unaware of?).

Or is there a way to attach the mutation observer to the document itself rather than an element?

I am sure the answer is simple but I can't find any documentation that covers this.

```
<body>
<script>
//I want to move this inline script into the <head>
var bodyList = document.querySelector("body"),
            observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                   console.log("MUTATION", mutation)
                });
            });
    observer.observe(bodyList, {childList: true, subtree: true});
</script>
....all the HTML elements that I want to monitor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an observer to the HTML document itself, wait for the `<body>` to appear, then attach an observer to the body:

```
// In the <head>:
new MutationObserver((_, observer) => {
    const { body } = document;
    if (!body) return;
    // Remove this observer, since it's not needed anymore; body exists
    observer.disconnect();
    new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            console.log("MUTATION", mutation)
        });
    })
        .observe(body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
})
    .observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense, I presume there is no way to do this without it being an inline script? i.e. I can't see previous mutations if I didn't initialise the `MutationObserver`, I know that seems like a dumb question but a complete noob with `MutationObserver`!

Comment: You can link the script in a separate file, if that's what you mean. If you wanted to do it without a `<script>` tag entirely, you could use an inline handler that errors immediately and runs the script, like an XSS attack would do, but that's really strange.

Comment: No it was just I meant that it has to appear and be executed before the `<body>` in order to capture all mutations on the page, if I added it via an external script that would mean I would only see mutations that occur after that script loads and is executed?

Comment: i.e. there is no `window.mutations` object that is generated (think similar to `window.performance` where you can call it later and still get all entires).

Comment: Sorry I am not being very clear. If I link the script in a separate file then I would only see mutations that occur after that file has been downloaded, parsed, compiled and executed. Assuming that file took 2 seconds to load I would not be able to access the mutations that occurred prior to that?

Comment: I don't know of a persistent mutation store. Scripts are blocking, so `<script>//content</script>` works just the same as `<script src="content.js"></script>` when it comes to when the script runs in relation to the page.

Comment: As I thought, I would never have an external blocking script on a page as it would kill load performance, so I guess inline is my only option. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It does indeed make the *first* load take longer, but it permits caching - further loads using the cached script will require less time (by a smidgen) because the cached file's contents doesn't need to be downloaded again. Depends what you value.

Comment: Yeah I am firmly in the "first time visitor performance" camp on that one :-P but a valid point nonetheless! Thanks for all the help!